# IE 8 still running compatibility mode even http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1"

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a problem with IE 8. The code goes

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" >
<title>My page</title>
</head>
```

Now for IE 8 version no `8.0.7601.17514` running in windows server 2008, the page loads in `Browser Mode: IE 8 compatibility mode` ,even when the compatibility mode button is disabled because of `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" >` .

But in another instance of IE 8 version no `8.0.6001.18702IS` (running in windows xp pro) is running fine in normal IE mode.

Can you help here? I want the page to load in normal IE 8 mode.

Comment: I am developing a intranet site. Even changing the code to
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>My Page</title>
</head>` didn't help as mentioned in [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960120/turn-off-ie-8-compatibility-mode-for-site[link]. Am i doing some wrong here

Comment: One more thing the Document Mode is IE 8 Standard but the Browser Mode is IE 8 Compatibility view. Thus the jquery `$.browser.version` gives 7.0

Comment: He clearly wants the latest rendering mode `transitional` will not trigger that. Instead he'd get some hybrid.

Comment: Can you post a link to a test page? Since you mention you get different results between two different computers it could be a local issue due to configuration on the Server 2008 computer.

Comment: @thomthom : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rituparnakashyap/PMTJs/show/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is late to the game, but I just had this problem.
This is/was for an intranet site with compatibility mode forced on and the compatibility mode button disabled.

Removing the DOCTYPE attribute corrected the forced compatibility mode.

Lodlaiden

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured out but somehow i forgot to conclude my own question.

Answer (score 3):

When using http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" make sure this meta-Tag is the first tag right after your head-tag.

this should solve your problem.